# Add instances in target group aws cli, shell script

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, tags, target

Wrote a script to add instances to the AWS target group

```
#!/bin/bash
export AWS_PROFILE=***
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-central-1

for INST_NAME in $(aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value' --output text | sort); do
    echo "check ${INST_NAME} in Target Group"
    TARGET_GROUP=$(aws elbv2 describe-target-groups|jq -r '.[]|.[].TargetGroupArn'| grep ${INST_NAME})
    RUNNING_INSTANCES=$(aws ec2 describe-instances| jq '.Reservations[].Instances[] | select(.Tags[].Value=="${INST_NAME}")'| jq -r .InstanceId| sort | uniq | wc -l)
    COUNT=$(aws elbv2 describe-target-health --target-group-arn ${TARGET_GROUP}|jq -r '.TargetHealthDescriptions[].Target.Id'| wc -l)
    if [[ ${RUNNING_INSTANCES} = ${COUNT} ]]; then
        echo "VSE OK"
    else 
        echo "dobavit ${RUNNING_INSTANCES} v ${TARGET_GROUP}"
        for INSTANCE_ID in $(aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name=tag-key,Values=Name --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].{Instance:InstanceId,Name:Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value}"|jq ".[][]|select(.Name==\"${TAGS}\")"|jq -r .Instance); do
            ASG=$(aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-instances|jq '.AutoScalingInstances'|jq ".[]|select(.InstanceId==\"${INSTANCE_ID}\")"|jq -r .InstanceId)
            echo "Updating ${TARGET_GROUP} to add instances from ${ASG}"
            aws elbv2 register-targets --target-group-arn ${TARGET_GROUP} --targets "Id="${ASG}
        done
    fi
done
```

but he doesn't add. Need select all instances by tag and compare with the number in the target group, if the number is different, then add all instances with the tag to the target group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update, it's working

```
for INSTANCE_NAME in $(aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value' --output text | sort | uniq ); do
echo "check ${INSTANCE_NAME} in Target Group"
TARGET_GROUP=$(aws elbv2 describe-target-groups|jq -r '.[]|.[].TargetGroupArn'| grep ${INSTANCE_NAME})
if ! [ -z "${TARGET_GROUP}" ]; then
    for i in $(echo ${TARGET_GROUP}); do
        RUNNING_INSTANCES=$(aws ec2 describe-instances| jq ".Reservations[].Instances[] | select(.Tags[].Value==\"${INSTANCE_NAME}\")"| jq -r .InstanceId| sort | uniq | wc -l)
        COUNT=$(aws elbv2 describe-target-health --target-group-arn ${i}|jq -r '.TargetHealthDescriptions[].Target.Id'| wc -l)
        if ! [[ ${RUNNING_INSTANCES} = ${COUNT} ]]; then 
            for INSTANCE_ID in $(aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name=tag-key,Values=Name --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].{Instance:InstanceId,Name:Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value}"|jq ".[][]|select(.Name==\"${INSTANCE_NAME}\")"|jq -r .Instance); do
                ASG=$(aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-instances|jq '.AutoScalingInstances'|jq ".[]|select(.InstanceId==\"${INSTANCE_ID}\")"|jq -r .InstanceId)
                aws elbv2 register-targets --target-group-arn ${i} --targets "Id="${ASG}
                echo "Updating ${TARGET_GROUP} to add instances from ${ASG}"
                
            done
        fi
    done
fi
```

done